# Why does this SphericalPlot3D instance seem defective?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Why is the vertical line circled in red discontinuous?

[image: plot]

Comment: what happens if you add say `PlotPoints->20` ?

Comment: How very odd. Here's a simpler way to reproduce: `SphericalPlot3D[5, θ, ϕ, Mesh -> 15]`. Setting the value of `Mesh` to any other integer does not display the gap.

Comment: Yes, fixed, why does it do that?

Comment: @J.M.  10.4 on my end, for reference

Comment: I did the test on 11.2. This is very peculiar indeed. As noted, tweaking `Mesh` or `PlotPoints` is a workaround for that unsightly gap.

Comment: Yay! My first "bug"! http://static2.businessinsider.com/image/5593f5cc6bb3f7ac51d8d3cf-1200-800/bug-6.jpg